# The space of absolutely convergent series is complete

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

For clarity:
$$ l^{1}(\mathbb{N}) = \left\{ (x_{n})_{n} \ \middle|\ \sum_{n}|x_{n}| \in\mathbb{R} \right\} $$
$$ d_{1}:\ l^{1}(\mathbb{N}) \times l^{1}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}:\ d_{1}((x_{n})_{n},(y_{n})_{n}) = \sum_{n}|x_{n}-y_{n}| $$

Theorem: $l^1(\mathbb{N}),d_1$ is complete

Here's my attempt:
Fix a Cauchy sequence $((x_{n,k})_{k})_{n})$ in $l^{1}(\mathbb{N})$ and an $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}$.
There then exists an $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\forall n,m\in\mathbb{N}:\ n,m\ge n_{0} \Rightarrow d_{1}\left(((x_{n,k})_{k},(x_{m,k})_{k}\right) < \epsilon$$
We know that all the series $\sum_{k}x_{n,k}$ converge absolutely, let's say to $x_n$

At this point I'm stuck.
I have no Idea how to use the series to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle \sum |x_{n,k}-x_{m,k}| < \epsilon$, then it's certainly true that $|x_{n,k}-x_{m,k}| < \epsilon$ for every $k$. This implies that, for fixed $k$, $\{x_{n,k}\}_n$ is Cauchy. This is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers, so it has some limit $x_k$. Thus, the sequence $\{x_{n,k}\}_n$ converges to some sequence $\{x_k\}$.

Can you prove $\{x_k\} \in l^1$?

Comment: Thank you! To prove that last statement, is this correct:?
$$\sum_{k}x_{k} = \sum_{k}\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(x_{n,k})_{n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{k}(x_{n,k})_{n} \in\mathbb{R} $$
Why does the second equality hold? The third one should hold because $l^1(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of *convergent* series.